# error when call WCF webservices function in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried to create a demo WCF webservice in visual studio 2010; I have added thr services reference successfully, but there's something wrong on the client still. If I try to call a function in the service I get an error.

Here's my code:

```
namespace BankAccount
{   
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IUserServices
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool addNewUser(User user);
    }
}

namespace BankAccount
{   
    public class UserServices : IUserServices
    {
        public bool addNewUser(User user)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = null;
            SqlCommand cmd = null;
            try
            {
                String sql = "insert into user(username,password,isActive) values(@username,@password,@isActive)";
                conn = Connection.getConnection();
                conn.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", user.getUsername()));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", user.getPassword()));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", user.getActive()));
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                return false;
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

//User object

```
public class User
    {
        private int Id;
        private String username;
        private String password;
        private Boolean isActive;

        public User()
        {

        }

        public int getId()
        {
            return this.Id;
        }

        public void setId(int id)
        {
            this.Id = id;
        }

        public String getUsername()
        {
            return this.username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username)
        {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getPassword()
        {
            return this.password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password)
        {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public Boolean getActive()
        {
            return this.isActive;
        }

        public void setActive(Boolean isActive)
        {
            this.isActive = isActive;
        }
    }
```

Client Site

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using BankClient.ServicesForUser;

namespace BankClient.userclient
{
    public partial class usersaving : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserServicesClient client = new UserServicesClient();
            //User on client project
            User user = new User();
            user.setUsername(txtusername.Text);
            user.setPassword(txtpassword.Text);
            user.setActive(true);

            bool result = client.addNewUser(user);
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error on the following line:

```
client.addNewUser(user)
```

Error:

```
the best overloaded method match for 'Bank.Client.ServicesName.UserServicesClient.addNewUser(Bank.Client.ServicesName.User) has some invalid arguments
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: What error exactly, and what did you try to resolve it?

Comment: Downvote for the exact reason above: **What** error? What have you tried?

Comment: hi men, you do not see that I said "I try to create a demo" by C#? and I have problem that I can not solve,therefore I post it on here to find the solution, it's not for jocking.

Comment: Try deleting the reference and adding it again

Comment: Dear Andrei,I have done the way that you said, but it still has error,thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You changed your user object after you created the service. Regenerate the service contract on the client.

It seems you are using the wrong user object:

```
        Bank.Client.ServicesName.User user = new Bank.Client.ServicesName.User();
        user.Username = txtusername.Text;
        user.Password = txtpassword.Text;
        user.Active = true;

        bool result = client.addNewUser(user);
```

Comment: Dear Peer, thanks advance for your reply,would you please give me the solution for it? thanksagain

Comment: how can I call the addNewUser(User user) on client ?

Comment: I have get and set functions in User object, but It have error: does not content a define for 'setUsername' and no extension method 'setUsername'(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference ?)...sorry for my bad English because I am Vietnamese

Comment: I changed the code, but you could have found the correction your self. If it does not work, post your server site user object, or check if the getters and setters are correct...

Comment: And you have to make sure you have the [DataMember] attributes on the serverside user object.

Comment: that is my problem, I missing [DataMember] in the property of User object